# Is there an extension or way to augment either Chrome or Firefox to assign a button to jump through wildcards such as ***?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I'm looking to work with a new EMR (electronic medical record) and was looking to add the ability to tab or f2 through what is called a wildcard in the medical field.

In essence, I will have a template similar to below.

"Patient presents today to follow up for ***. The patient is *** years old"

I would then hit a button f2 in the case of EPIC that would allow me to bounce to each "***" to type in what I would like to add. I've confirmed the new EMR doesn't have this option. I haven't been able to find an extension or setting within chrome or firefox that would allow me to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use Find - clunky but predictable.

Comment: You should contact the provider of the software, to get this added as a feature. Or their trainers may have a more efficient way of using the system. I used to work in healthcare, testing primary care (GP) systems. They often aren't designed with end users in mind, unfortunately.

Comment: E.g. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-regex-search/bpelaihoicobbkgmhcbikncnpacdbknn - regex searches should be way more accurate with `\b***\b`, if I understand your issue correctly.

Comment: I suppose it may be possible, using a 3rd party automation tool such as AutoHotKey, to do this. I have no idea how it would be done, but it seems like something AHK could do. However, due to the sensitivity of EMR data and systems, I would guess getting approval to install and run an automation tool like this may be difficult, or impossible.